# Reduce munin logging level

Tags: monitoring, logging, syslog, munin, filter

Munin is quite verbose, and logs a bunch of things into `munin-graph.log`, `munin-html.log`, `munin-limits.log` and `munin-update.log` at each run of `munin-cron`.

I already reduced munin-node logging level by setting `log_level 0` in [munin-node.conf](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/munin-node.conf), and that works well. `munin-node.log` only gets updated when an error message is generated.

However I also tried to add the same option in `munin.conf`, but it makes munin crash.

How one can reduce the amount of logs written by munin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to figure out which fields were allowed in munin.conf, I ended up reading the source code of [Config.pm](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/blob/2.0.7/master/lib/Munin/Master/Config.pm).

Unfortunately, the only references to logging are the followings:

```
config      => bless ( {
   debug            => 0,
   logdir           => $Munin::Common::Defaults::MUNIN_LOGDIR,
}, $class )
```

But looking further at the source code shows some [recent commits](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/commit/8ad5dda8f8b5f681a73a5ad3e5348ccb4cc1241d) on the messages logged:

```
@@ -90,7 +90,7 @@ while (new CGI::Fast) {
   my $pinpoint = undef;
   my $path = $ENV{PATH_INFO} || "";

-  INFO "Request path is $path";
+  DEBUG "Request path is $path";

   # The full URL looks like this:
   # Case 1:

@@ -133,7 +133,7 @@ while (new CGI::Fast) {
   my ($dom, $host, $serv, $scale) =
     $path =~ m#^/(.*)/([^/]+)/([\w-]+)-([\w=,]+)\.png#; ## avoid bug in vim

-  INFO "asked for ($dom, $host, $serv, $scale)";
+  DEBUG "asked for ($dom, $host, $serv, $scale)";

   if ($scale =~ /pinpoint=(\d+),(\d+)/) {
     $pinpoint = [ $1, $2, ];
```

I upgraded munin to 2.0.6-1 as I was running [Debian stable's 1.4.5-3](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/munin) and logging was indeed reduced !